# Gaining intuition over Hamiltonian for qubit systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, noise

A typical Hamiltonian for a two state system with some driving field can be written as $$H=J(t)\sigma_z+h\sigma_x$$ This represents a qubit system driven along a single axis.

On the other hand we can model qubit systems in an environment at its simplest form(or noise) by including a stochastic function in the Hamiltonian. For example: $$H=-B\sigma_Z-\vec b(t)\cdot\vec \sigma $$

Comparing the two Hamiltonian we can see that in the case of random functions we have it coupled to all three $\sigma$ matrices in the Hamiltonian. I have difficulty in gaining intuition over the particular form of Hamiltonian in the above cases. My understanding is that because we are modelling noise, we don't have control over "which axis it should effect"  and thus we take the general case of $\vec b(t)\cdot \vec \sigma$ instead of something like $b(t)\cdot\sigma_x$. Is my intuition correct?

If it is, then, what about a qutrit case. Will $$H=B\lambda_8-\vec S(t)\cdot\vec \lambda$$ be a possible Hamiltonian for a qutrit system with noise? Here, the $\lambda$s are the Gell-Mann matrices and thus $\vec S(t)$ has eight components.

Comment: You can model noise without assuming that it couples to all three $\sigma$ matrices, i.e. a noise term of the form $b(t)\sigma^x$ models many situations perfectly well.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Could you give me an example of a physical situation where it could work?

Comment: Basically any qubit that is not a spin-$1/2$, so that the Pauli operators do not represent different directions in physical space but rather different kinds of coupling. Then if the environment couples in a certain way, only one component of your $b$ vector will be non-zero. Examples include a quantum dot qubit coupled to phonon fluctuations in the substrate, or an atomic hyperfine qubit coupled to density fluctuations in a surrounding gas.

Comment: Ohh great. What about a qutrit? Is the above Hamiltonian the most general form for a qutrit system with noise? General in the sense that it is coupled to all 8 Gell-Mann matrices.